# How to scale and crop an image with php-imagick?

Tags: php, image, crop, imagick

I use [jQuery Guillotine](http://guillotine.js.org/) to position a preloaded image. Guillotine returns an array similar to this one:

```
array (
    'scale' => '0.13186813186813187',
    'angle' => '0',
    'x' => '45',
    'y' => '0',
    'w' => '180',
    'h' => '180'
)
```

Now I can crop the image like this:

```
$url = 'https://s.yimg.com/uy/build/images/sohp/inspiration/love-rock3.jpg';

$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageFile(fopen($url, 'rb'));
$image->cropImage($size['w'], $size['h'], $size['x'], $size['y']);

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

But how to zoom in? I have `scale` which is the zoom factor I guess. Does Imagick provide a way to pass a zoom factor?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with zoom? You want to scale the picture to a specific width and height?

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

to crop and resize an image in one step take a closer look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php#119086

Answer (score 0):

imagick has zooming by crop. It is called the crop zoom. You shall read it from here before implementing.
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18065

Here you will find the examples as well.